# powershell word table borders

Tags: powershell, ms-word

i'm looking for a bit of help in how to set table border properties in a word document.

I have a pre formatted word document that i'm inserting information from a windows form.

so far I found a post relating to this on here with the below line which inserts a  border around each cell:

```
$Table.cell($x,1).range.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = 1
```

What im trying to achieve is, say I have 4 bits of information that are being inserted, I want a border around the entire 4 cells to make it one block (if that makes sense)

I found a c# example using the borders object however im struggling to work out how to use it in powershell:

```
$table.cell($x,1).Range.Borders[WdBorderType.wdBorderLeft].LineStyle   = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
$table.cell($x,1).Range.Borders[WdBorderType.wdBorderRight].LineStyle  = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
```

I think I need to use something like the below

```
"[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment]::wdAlignParagraphCenter"
```

Can some one give me some guidance?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to first load Word assembly in to the memory. Then use it:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word"
$pCenter = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment]::wdAlignParagraphCenter
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply

is was actually

$wdBorderBottom = "-3"
$wdBorderLeft = "-2"
$wdBorderRight = "-4"

        $Table.cell($x,4).range.Borders.item($wdBorderRight).LineStyle = 1
        $Table.cell($x,4).range.Borders.item($wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = 1
        $Table.cell($x,4).range.Borders.item($wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = 0

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using:

```
$wdBorderBottom = "-3"
$wdBorderLeft = "-2"
$wdBorderRight = "-4"
$Table.cell($x,4).range.Borders.item($wdBorderRight).LineStyle = 1
$Table.cell($x,4).range.Borders.item($wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = 1
$Table.cell($x,4).range.Borders.item($wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = 0
```

Thanks